# Do I Substitute Values into an Equation Before or After Simplification of the Expression and Why?

Tags: linear-algebra, substitution

Considering the equation:
\begin{align} y&=\dfrac{6x+x^2}{x}
&\text{(before simplification)}\\ y&=6+x &\text{(after simplification).} \end{align}

- If Before Simplification of the expression, $x = 0$ is substituted,
  $y = undefined$
- But after Simlfication, $x = 0$ is substituted, $y =
     6$

Why is this so? Or am I getting something wrong?

Comment: Your expression is defined for every $x\ne0$. You can use $\dfrac{a\pm b}{c}=\dfrac{a}{c}\pm\dfrac{b}{c}$ only if $c\ne0$.

Comment: so u can see when u go from first to second u will divide by the x. but when x=0 u cannot divide by x so the second is simplify of the first if x not=0.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you did the simplification *almost* correct. The actual correct simplification would be
$$y = x + 6, \quad x \neq 0$$
because that's what captures all information in the original equation. If you forget the $x \neq 0$, you lose that piece of information, and that leads to your confusion.

Answer (score 1):

$$y = \frac{6x+x^2}{x} = \frac{x(6+x)}{x}$$
Now, you cannot cancel out the $x$ if $x = 0$ because division by zero is undefined. Your simplification is valid for any $x \neq 0$
$$  y = 6+x ~~~\forall ~x \neq 0 $$
Another thing to note here is that the domain of $y(x)$ is $\mathbb{R} - \{0\} $ which means that $y$ is not defined at $x=0$. Therefore, the graph of $y(x)$ will be a straight line ($y=x+6$) missing the point $(0,6)$. However, if you plot $y=x+6$ , the graph will be a straight line including $(0,6)$. Apart from the point $(0,6)$, both the graphs are identical.

Comment: thanks a lot, I definitely understand what you said, but it just seems awkward to me that zero is different from other numbers, meaning that for every form of an equation having an expression divided by a zero, one must always include the mathematical statement: " for all 'x' not equal to 0 " after every simplification?...hmm, I also guess this is because of how 6*0  is defined(i.e as Zero) and lead to some sort of loss of information or value. If only (6*0 is not 0) but left as (6*0) literarily and 0/0 is 1, this would not happen(I mean Zero would act as other numbers...).So (6*0)/0 = 6

Comment: @Atolz Zero is different from other numbers in the sense that division by zero is undefined. Also, the mathematical statement is non necessarily that 'for all x not equal to zero'. For example, $$\dfrac{(x-5)(x+3)}{x-5} = x+3 ~~ \forall x ~ \neq 5$$

Comment: I have been wondering what 0/0,0/6,6*0,6/0 means, it drains my energy

Comment: @Atolz $\dfrac06 = 0$ and $6 \times 0 = 0$. $\\$ $\dfrac00$ and $\dfrac60$ are undefined

Comment: this all came up due to "instantaneous velocity" when both dy and dx are Zero at a point

Comment: @Atolz Are you sure there wasn't any limit involved? $\dfrac00$ makes a lot more sense when you are considering a limit. It is one of the many indeterminate forms.

Comment: hmm, thanks, this means I'll have to research why 0/6=0 and 6/0,0/0=undefined

Comment: the concept of limits seems shady to me because I noticed that dy is actually 0 when dx=0, but when we divide both sides by dx before substitution of 0, and we get the dy/dx value(not undefined) which is usually what is called Limit. That's why I suspect 0/0 should not neccessirily be undefined but preserved as 0/0 and 6/0 as 6/0,and the likes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118738/discussion-between-ankit-saha-and-atolz).